# Twitter Rest API: 404 No user matches for specified terms

Tags: rest, twitter, twython, twitter-rest-api

Twitter allows up to 100 user ids at a time to query for user profile information. But if there is an invalid ID among those, it returns:

```
404 (Not Found), No user matches for specified terms
```

without specifying which is the bad ID and no data is returned for the rest of the users in the list. This happens if a user in the list closes their account.

Is there a way to identify the invalid ID without going through the list once again one by one (and possibly hitting the rate limit)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-lookup.html

> - If a requested user is unknown, suspended, or deleted, then that user will not be returned in the results list.
> - If none of your lookup criteria can be satisfied by returning a user object, a HTTP 404 will be thrown.

From my understanding this means:

- If you request 10 userIds and 1 of them is suspended, the request should still return 9 results
- If you request 2 userIds and all of them are suspended, the request will return that error

I did a quick test and it seems to work as described.
Could it be that all of the IDs in your request are invalid?

Answer (score -1):

You can use puts command for printing user id on first loop and you can see your log file or console to get the user id which is invalid.

Comment: thanks, but what do you mean by "first loop"? do you suggest first checking the users one by one? i want to avoid hitting twitter once for each user in the list, as i've stated in the question.

Comment: If you want to just skip the invalid user and go on with the valid  you can work on exception handling.

Comment: using exception handling you will be able to skip the id with error and code with not stop. if and user id is invalid

Comment: ok, sure, but i'm fetching 100 user at once, i.e. with a single query. this is the twitter limit. i am not doing it one by one. and if a user fails in that batch of 100, it does not tell which one.

Comment: okay which language you are using ? can you paste your code here?